# Return unicode characters when search with nomal character in datatable

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I am writing a Winform application and i want to filter a datatable to display on my gridview.

In SQL Server I can write:

```
SELECT [status] 
FROM   articles 
WHERE  [status] LIKE '%B[iìí?]nh%'
```

This returns all record which contain 'Binh', 'Bình', 'Bính', 'Bịnh', 'Bỉnh'.

Is there any way to do this with datatable? I have used:

```
Datarow[] dr = dt.Select("status like '%B[iìíị]nh%'");
```

But it does not work.

Comment: why do you do the select in the data row step? why not in the dt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### First alternative

An idea would be to use **regular expressions and LINQ**:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Data;

static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("status");
        dt.Rows.Add("Binh");
        dt.Rows.Add("Bình");
        dt.Rows.Add("Bính");
        dt.Rows.Add("Bịnh");
        dt.Rows.Add("Bỉnh");
        dt.Rows.Add("Aing");
        var result = dt.AsEnumerable()
            .Where(row => 
                Regex.Match(row.Field<string>("status"), @"B[iìíị]nh").Success)
            .ToList();
    }
}
```

You might want to create an extension method for the `DataTable`:

```
public static DataRow[] 
    RegexSearch(this DataTable dt, string column, string pattern)
{
    var regex = new Regex(pattern);
    return dt.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(row =>
        regex.Match(row.Field<string>(column)).Success)
    .ToArray();
}
```

with the following sample usage:

```
var result = dt.RegexSearch("status", "A[iìíị]n");
```

### Second alternative

There is also another approach which might render interesting for you: **use a second column**, `statusNormalized`, which will store the *normalized* version of the text in the `status` column. When you do the searching, use this column as the search target. This will require also that you normalize the searched text.

So, create a class which will hold the normalization mappings:

```
public static class NormalizationMapping
{
    public static Dictionary<string, Regex> EncodingMapping;
    static NormalizationMapping()
    {
        if (EncodingMapping == null)
        {
            EncodingMapping = new Dictionary<string, Regex>();
            string strRegex = @"[iìíịỉî]";
            EncodingMapping.Add("i", new Regex(strRegex, 
                RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase));
            strRegex = @"[aăâ]";
            EncodingMapping.Add("a", new Regex(strRegex, 
                RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase));
            strRegex = @"[eě]";
            EncodingMapping.Add("e", new Regex(strRegex,
                RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase));
            strRegex = @"[uú]";
            EncodingMapping.Add("u", new Regex(strRegex, 
                RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase));
            //TODO: add all your mappings
        }
    }
}
```

When you create the datatable, add an handler for the row changed event and also the aforementioned `statusNormalized` column:

```
var dt = new DataTable();
dt.RowChanged += dt_RowChanged;

dt.Columns.Add("status");
dt.Columns.Add("statusNormalized");
```

The event handler should look like this:

```
static void dt_RowChanged(object sender, DataRowChangeEventArgs e)
{
    e.Row.Table.RowChanged -= dt_RowChanged;
    e.Row["statusNormalized"] = e.Row["status"].ToString().ToLower();
    foreach (var kvPair in NormalizationMapping.EncodingMapping)
    {
        e.Row["statusNormalized"] = kvPair.Value
            .Replace(e.Row["statusNormalized"].ToString(), kvPair.Key);
    }
    e.Row.AcceptChanges();
    e.Row.Table.RowChanged += dt_RowChanged;
}
```

and we will also need an extension method in order to normalize the searched text:

```
public static string
    CustomNormalize(this string text)
{
    foreach (var kvPair in NormalizationMapping.EncodingMapping)
    {
        text = kvPair.Value.Replace(text, kvPair.Key);
    }
    return text;
}
```

The sample usage will look now like this:

```
var searchedText = "bînh";
var result = dt.Select("statusNormalized like '%" + 
    searchedText.CustomNormalize() + "%'");
```

---

I'd rather go for the second alternative, as it is easier to work with for the user and presumably faster in terms of search performance.

Comment: It works,Thank you very much.
Because i don't know how to write linq, Can you make it case insensitive ?

Comment: @Victor: Use the [Regex.Match overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bk1x0726(v=vs.110).aspx) that allows you to specify [options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions(v=vs.110).aspx) as the third argument. The `IgnoreCase` option is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

`DataTable.Select` supports only a limited subset of SQL WHERE conditions, which is described on the

- [MSDN page for the DataColumn.Expression Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

According to that, `LIKE` only supports wildcards *at the beginning or the end of an expression*, and `[.]` is only used to escape a value, not to provide alternatives.

Thus, if you stick to using `DataTable.Select`, you will have to workaround this using `OR` clauses:

```
Datarow[] dr = dt.Select("status like '%Binh%' OR " +
                         "status like '%Bình%' OR " +
                         "status like '%Bính%' OR " +
                         "status like '%Bịnh%'");
```

(Programmatically converting one format to the other is left as an exercise to the reader.)

Comment: Thank you, this code works but the keyword is dynamic so this solution is not appropriate